# React, read const from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this 2 components:

`BasicMaintainer`

```
// etc...
import GeneratingUnit from "./generating-unit";

class BasicMaintainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // etc...
  }

  // etc...

  handleOnSelectFile = event => {
    here I want to use: GeneratingUnit.columns.length
  }
```

The other component `GeneratingUnit`is:

```
import React from 'react';
//...code

export const columns = [
    {name: 'ID', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'id'},
    {name: 'NOMBRE', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'nombre'},
    {name: 'DESCRIPCIÓN', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'descripcion'},
    {name: 'IT UNIDAD GENERADORA', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'it_unidad_generadora'},
]

const GeneratingUnit = props => <div>
    //code...
</div>

export default GeneratingUnit;
```

How can I use `const columns` in `handleOnSelectFile` of `BasicMaintainer` component?

Comment: You can save columns to state, and later pass state to basicMaintainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import it in your `BasicMaintainer` file:

```
import GeneratingUnit, {columns} from "./generating-unit";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't modify this variable:
remove `columns` variable from component and put in the current module in the shared folder with global variables and functions, and import in your components.

```
folder: shared
file: index.js
```

index.js

```
export const columns = [
    {name: 'ID', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'id'},
    {name: 'NOMBRE', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'nombre'},
    {name: 'DESCRIPCIÓN', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'descripcion'},
    {name: 'IT UNIDAD GENERADORA', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, key: 'it_unidad_generadora'},
]
```

in components:

```
import { columns } from "./shared";
```